# Related List for external object not showing any records in Lightning (SharePoint Online)

Tags: related-list, externalobjects, sharepoint

I am having problems with displaying data from external data source in Lightning. I have a connection to SharePoint Online while using Indirect Lookup relationship to match external data with Accounts.

Everything works fine in Classic (data are matched as expected, displaying in Related List correctly), but after going into Salesforce Lightning, in some cases, there aren't any data present in the Related List.

I've found this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000erW7QAI&title=related-list-for-external-object-not-showing-any-records-in-lightning

As you can see in the Known Issue page above, there isn't any fix yet and the only workaround is to check how the data are handled by OData producer (SharePoint) or if the External Column Name is/isn't Case Sensitive.

Is it possible to check or modify the OData that are passed from SharePoint to Salesforce? Do you have an experience with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with this specific problem, but it would seem there are a number of things you could do to help yourself diagnose how to deal with it in your code. First, you don't say if you're using OData 2 or 4 (read-only vs read-write). I'm going to assume you're only reading the data. Your configuration should be readily available for you to review in setup for the field types.

If its working fine in Classic but not in Lightning, that should tell you something about the nature of your problem by collecting some more information on what you're doing differently in Lightning than what you're doing in Classic.

Are you using the Related List Component in Lightning for example as opposed to the related list that's available on the Detail layout? The Detail layout is common between both Classic and Lightning. If you add the related list for this item to your Detail layout on a Lightning Page and don't rely on the Related List Component to display it, does that solve your problem? I strongly suspect it might due to the way the Related List Component is coded in JS as a Lightning Component.

Another thing that might be worth trying is to use the Related Object List component to see if it displays any differently (I wouldn't expect it to, but it might). There's also a free Lightning Component on the App Exchange Called myDynPro that I've been working with that might also do what you're trying to accomplish without needing to write any code. It has a great deal of flexibility and may just do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that there isn't any custom code. This is a "standardized" connection made using Salesforce OData connector. There's too little I can do and change. I've had an idea - try to see what SharePoint is sending within the OData (probably 2, it's only read-only). But I don't know where to find this inside SharePoint online.

Comment: I think you may have missed something that's crucial in my answer. The Account DETAIL Page Layout is the same between Classic and Lightning. If one works and the other doesn't, make certain the Lightning Record Page created in App Builder displays the related lists as part of the Object's Detail page, NOT by using the `Related List Component`. SharePoint likely has very little to do with your problem. It's likely an issue with the Component and with not using the related list that's on the Account Detail Layout for your OData Connected Object.

Comment: Understood, the layout is the same for Classic and Lightning. Lightning Record Page has standard Record Detail component and Related Lists component in it. I think there are three options how to display Related Lists in Lightning: **1)** Related Lists component (it's driven by assigned layout). **2)** Related List (select single list), **3)** Related List Quick Links (only shortcuts). I'm using option **1)**, which I think is correct and it's what you were talking about. But the problem persist. I agree the problem is in Lightning, it was even caught by Salesforce (see link above).

Comment: All of the things in the related list you've referred to from the known issue would be configured in the O-data connector and Object setup.

Comment: I understand that, but the workaround mentioned on the Known Issue page doesn't work. I don't know where to turn to, probably nowhere since it doesn't have any other workaround solutions as of now. I'll probably need to wait on Salesforce to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here to agree with and thank crmprogdev - thanks to the point about the account detail page layout being the same in classic/lightning (unlike the 'lightning only' related tab being used on the lightnign record page I'm working on), I was able to add different related list components and compare results. I concluded this is a dynamic related list component issue for external objects. When I added the "Related List - Single", the External Object child list did show. Happily I was able to validate this on Salesforce help pages: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000HDb4PSAT. Would love a newer reference/link to the documentation though!

For anyone coming into this just looking to get started on adding a related list for an external object, this is a useful page: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-lightning-connect/quickstart-lightning-connect3